# How to properly bundle material ui with a react component npm package

Tags: reactjs, webpack, material-ui

I'm having issues bundling material ui with my react component package. The error im getting is this after bundling.

> × Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the
> body of a function component. This could happen for one of the
> following reasons:

[image]

This is the simple component,

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import { createMuiTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import InputAdornment from "@material-ui/core/InputAdornment";
import GifIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Gif";
import { Grid } from "@material-ui/core";
type CommentType = {
  style?: object;
};
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#48A9A6",
    },
    secondary: {
      main: "#000000",
    },
  },
});

class CommentBox extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Grid>Owls are cool</Grid>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}
export default CommentBox;
```

and this is where its being called (in another project)

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import CommentBox from "commentbox-simple-demo";
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CommentBox />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**This error only happens if i use material ui components in the component. Components such as grid, typography, etc.**

What could i be doing wrong ?

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  entry: "./src/index.ts",
  output: {
    filename: "index.js",
    path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    libraryTarget: "commonjs2",
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts|tsx|js?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ["ts-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".jsx"],
  },
};
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "jsx": "react",
    "declaration": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked all the points mentioned in the error message?

Comment: Yes. I do not have an idea why using material ui is throwing error upon using components.

Comment: what could `index.js:1 Fetch API cannot load webpack:///./node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js?. URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request` this mean ?

Comment: Bro, just use create-react-app 

Comment: I don't understand what you mean ? this is an npm package, and i cant use create-react-app when bundling a react package component.

Comment: Ah sorry, haven't read your question proberly. I made an npm package with react and material-ui too and everything works fine. You may have a look on it https://github.com/Tracer1337/react-mui-swipeable

Comment: I went through it, you're not using webpack for this so its hard to relate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it, I had to remove `react` and `react-dom` from my package component, and reinstall the package on the demo app. So i guess to avoid invalid hook error, i need to have `react` and `react-dom`  folder removed from my package component, and then try reinstalling

This was tutorial was helpful

https://juliangaramendy.dev/react-typescript-library-tsdx/